# Iterate over all links/sub-links with Scrapy run from script

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to run Scrapy Spider from my script, but it works only for 1 request. I cannot execute the procedure **self.parse_product** from `scrapy.http.Request(product_url, callback=self.parse_product)`.

I guess it's being due the command `crawler.signals.connect(callback, signal=signals.spider_closed)`. Please advise how correctly go over all links and sub-links.

Whole script is shown below.

```
import json
import scrapy

from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose, TakeFirst
from scrapy import log, signals, Spider, Item, Field
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from twisted.internet import reactor

# https://gist.github.com/alecxe/fc1527d6d9492b59c610

# define an item class
class WebStoreItem(Item):
    name = Field()
    price = Field()
    developer = Field()
    date_added = Field()
    date_modified = Field()
    votes = Field()
    views = Field()
    sales = Field()
    avg_rating = Field()
    comments = Field()


# define an item loader with input and output processors
class WebStoreItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    desc_out = Join()


# define a pipeline
class JsonWriterPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open('items.json', 'wb')

    def __del__(self):
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item


# define a spider
class WebStoreSpider(Spider):
    name = "WebStore"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.WebStore.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.WebStore.com/index.php"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for meta in response.xpath('//div[@class="extension-grid"]'):
            for product_block in meta.xpath('//div[@class="image-holder image"]'):
                item = WebStoreItem()
                avg_rating = meta.xpath('//div[@class="rating"]/text()').extract()[0]
                item['avg_rating'] = avg_rating[avg_rating.find(': ') + 1:].strip()
                comment = meta.xpath('//div[@class="comment"]/text()').extract()[0]
                item['comments'] = comment[comment.find(': ') + 1:].strip()

                print 'product_block: ', product_block
                product_url = product_block.xpath('a[1]/@href').extract()[0]
                print 'product_url: ', product_url

                request = scrapy.http.Request(product_url, callback=self.parse_product)
                request.meta['item'] = item
                yield request


    def parse_product(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        product_meta_block = response.xpath('//div[@class="name"]')
        print 'product_meta_block: ', product_meta_block
        product_rows = product_meta_block.xpath('//tr)')
        print 'product_rows: ', product_rows
        i = 0
        for row in product_rows:
            if i == 1:
                item['name'] = row.select('td/text()').extract()
            elif i == 3:
                item['votes'] = row.select('td/text()').extract()
            i += 1
        return item


# callback fired when the spider is closed
def callback(spider, reason):
    stats = spider.crawler.stats.get_stats()  # collect/log stats?

    # stop the reactor
    reactor.stop()


def stop_reactor():
    reactor.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # instantiate settings and provide a custom configuration
    settings = Settings()
    settings.set('ITEM_PIPELINES', {
        '__main__.JsonWriterPipeline': 100
    })


    # instantiate a crawler passing in settings
    crawler = Crawler(settings)

    # instantiate a spider
    spider = WebStoreSpider()

    # configure signals
    crawler.signals.connect(callback, signal=signals.spider_closed)

    # configure and start the crawler
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    crawler.start()


    # start logging
    log.start()

    # start the reactor (blocks execution)
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spider is being blocked from visiting pages after the start page by your `allowed_domains` specification.  The value should include just the *domain*, not the *protocol*.  Try

```
allowed_domains = ["www.WebStore.com"]
```

Also the line `desc_out = Join()` in your `WebStoreItemLoader` definition may give an error as you have no `desc` field.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works `allowed_domains = ["www.WebStore.com"]`